# Writing to a temporary file in java

Tags: java

I want to write to a temporary file in an append mode. I see that the file is created but the data from the Stringbuffer is not getting written to it. Can somebody tell me why? Please find below the code I have written,

```
public static void writeToFile(String pFilename, StringBuffer sb)
        throws IOException {

    String property = "java.io.tmpdir";


    String tempDir = System.getProperty(property);

    File dir = new File(tempDir);
    File filename = File.createTempFile(pFilename, ".tmp", dir);
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename.getName(), true);
    System.out.println(filename.getName());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: How do you know the data is not getting written to it? [The 2-argument `File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method does nothing to specify the directory, by the way.

Comment: @Matt: the file is created but i dont see any data in the file and also is it possible to the files created without the random numbers being generated.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors with your StringBuffer contents? Try and write a "Hello, World!" string to the file.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(filename.getName());` print?

Comment: (*Side note: are you using a StringBuffer because you have multiple threads to contend with? If not, use StringBuilder*).

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder.

Comment: `File.createTempFile()` creates a file with a unique/random part to its name.  This means you are making it hard to read the same file later unless you keep the `File filename`

Comment: @Tichodroma: it prints Output_new.txt5600882239146137174.tmp

Comment: @DuncanJones I don't think using StringBuffer across multiple threads is a good idea even. Actually I don't think StringBuffer being thread safe was ever a good idea. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: @user1688404 And when you read this file, as you sayings its empty?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I think i'll ahve to change that because i need to reuse the file agin

Comment: @user1688404 You could return the file created and re-use it that way.

Comment: BTW `File filename = File.createTempFile(pFilename, ".tmp");` creates the file in the "tmp" directory by default.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: i want to create the file in the System/temp directory but dont have the system generated random filename because the next time i want to append to this same file. how can i achieve that??

Comment: `File filename = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), pFilename+".tmp");`

Comment: I would place this code in a static method so you can get this `File` for other purposes e.g. if you want to read the file and delete it later.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: my code is already in the static block. did u mean something else..?

Comment: The line of code to turn a `pFilename` into a `File`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename.getName(), true);
```

should be

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
```

Comment: [`FileWriter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String)) exists. Since `filename` in the question acually is a `File`, this constructor should work with [`File.getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()).

Comment: Also FileWriter(String,boolean append) exists so whatever tichodroma said is correct

Comment: @Joop: Thanks it works.. but is possible to the generate filenames without the random numbers being generated

Comment: One can use a prefix with [File.createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)).

Comment: @user1688404 Why do the numbers trouble you? They exist in order to ensure uniqueness. As Joop Eggen suggests, you can add a prefix to the name if that's important to you.

Comment: @DuncanJones. the random number troubles me because, this is a like a log file and i need to append information to this file the next time the program runs. so, if a random number is generated, it is difficult to pick the file.

Comment: With createTempFile one can parametrize the call so that all files start with a fixed prefix, and then follows a random number, say "aaaaa" + rand + "-bbb.ccc".

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
public static void writeToFile(String pFilename, StringBuffer sb) throws IOException {
    File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(pFilename, ".tmp", tempDir);
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
    System.out.println(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    bw.close();
}
```

Note the usage of [`FileWriter(File, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) and of [`System.out.println(tempFile.getAbsolutePath())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating file in temp directory , create the file in your working directory and use `objFile.deleteOnExit()`.It will also work the same as creating file in temp dir.

Comment: Why do you think this is a better idea that getting a working temporary file?

Comment: it's not the better idea , but it's an alternative, it will work.

Comment: @Vijay, i want to create this file in the System Temp folder and then need to append to this file new data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `bw.flush()` before closing the writer. Although I think that writer should call flush automatically before being closed...

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename.getName(), true);
```

should be

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
```

you can also use this

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename.getAbsolutePath+filename.getName(), true);
```

note

```
`filename.getName();`
```

returns the filename without the absolute path. So there might be the case that it is creating a file in the Present working directory and writing into it.