# How can Java handle very big clipboard contents using files?

Tags: java, swing, file, clipboard

I found, that Java is unable to save very big content to system clipboard using functions like `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(text), owner)`. The exact value of the maximum size depends on the computer. For an example Windows PC it is around 20 MB.

My idea is to store big content to files instead. The Transferable object itself should only manage the temporary filename and maybe other metadata.

I am searching working example code for this task.

My example code is minimal. It only shows how to do the "copy action". After starting the example the user can use "paste" in some application. The UTF-8 encoded content of the file "bigfile.txt" is pasted to the application.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SimpleClipboardWithFile extends JDialog
    implements ClipboardOwner
{
    public SimpleClipboardWithFile(Frame parent, boolean modal)
    {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

        DataFlavor df = new DataFlavor("text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; "
                       + "charset=UTF-8", "text/plain");
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
        getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable trans = new Transferable() {
            @Override
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
            {
                return new DataFlavor[]{df};
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
            {
                return df.equals(flavor);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
            {
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                getSystemClipboard();
                Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(this);
                // TODO: take filename from Transferable object
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("bigfile.txt");
                return input;
            }
        };
        clipboard.setContents(trans, this);
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Do \"paste\" in an application");

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            SimpleClipboardWithFile dialog = new SimpleClipboardWithFile(new JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                    {
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Your idea seems good to me. You may use temporary files for such, that is what they are for: [Writing to a temporary file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13251003/2411243)
You then only need to save hold the path to that file. If you then want to read the data, resolve the file path.